# TypeError: player.currentTime is not a function error in videojs

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

I have a working player in videojs and I'm trying to get the current position of the progress bar, In the documentation provided by videojs they use myPlayer.currentTime() to get and set the time in seconds but it is not working for me.

My code:

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    host: "https://www.youtube.com",
    /* no need to specify player 
    size here since it is handled 
    by the player-size div */
    videoId: video_id,
    playerVars: {
      enablejsapi: 1,
      playsinline: 1,
      start: 0,
      disablekb: 0
    },
    events: {
      onReady: onPlayerReady,
      onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  console.log("player state: " + player.getPlayerState());

  if (player.getPlayerState() == 2){
    console.log("STOPED AT:" + player.currentTime()); // This is where i want to log the current time of the playing video
  }
}

function updateVideoId(video_id) {
  player.loadVideoById(video_id, -1);
}

function stopVideo() {
  player.stopVideo();
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is YouTube's API, not Video.js.

If you want to play a YouTube video in Video.js and use Video.js's API, you need to use the [YouTube tech for Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube)